# Java 8 collect, count with sum

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a data in the following format:

```
ProductName | Date
------------|------
ABC         | 1-May
ABC         | 1-May
XYZ         | 1-May
ABC         | 2-May
```

It is in the form of List, where Product consists of ProductName and Date. Now I wanted to group these data and get the count with sum as follows:

```
1-May
  -> ABC : 2
  -> XYZ : 1
  -> Total : 3
2-May
  -> ABC: 1
  -> Total : 1
```

So far what I've achieved is grouping with counting, but not the total value.

```
myProductList.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getDate, 
            Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getProductName, Collectors.counting())));
```

Not sure how do I get the total value.

Comment: The first and IMHO crucial question is: Where and how should the "total" be represented? It should probably *not* be a plain map entry. (Not only because of the odd case of a product with `productName="Total"`. I'd rather consider something that has a real *structure* - maybe even involving a class `ProductSummary` where the "total" is a field, or something similar). Apart from that, subjectively: If I saw code like that from the current answers in a code review, I'd ask the author to rewrite it. Sometimes a plain `for` loop is just *better* than deeply nested stream+lambda magic...

Comment: I agree with you @Marco13. That was my first argument with my front end engineer. He wanted in this format as he will just use the table to show this data with each product quantity along with the total as the last column. Whatever you had suggested is always a best approach to handle, however not working at my place.

Comment: @Marco13 Although I understand what you mean, I don't agree. When Java 8 was released, everything was done with streams and lambdas. A `for` and an `if` were considered to be old and bad style. Now that trend has finished, and `for` and `if` have come back with all their strength to remind us they are valuable for a lot of problems. And we start to see long, nested streams and collectors as bad practice... For me, it will always be a matter of taste. It might even depend on the mood of the code reviewer on that particular day.

Comment: shmosel's answer perfectly shows how to move the downstream collector logic out to a helper method, so that nested collectors don't make your eyes pain. And my own answer shows (in its second part) how to do the job with a custom collector, which is more maintainable and efficient. If I had my code reviewed and I was told to rewrite my custom collector because *sometimes a plain for loop is just better than deeply nested stream+lambda magic*, then I think I'd start looking for another job...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I agree with what you said about the role of streams (basically, some sort of a "hype cycle"). And one could argue about style, and the fact that you just have to "get used to" read a certain style of code, or that you can [intentionally go too far](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79082) with functional programming. But the point (for me) here is: There are several operations to be done here - basically grouping and counting. Trying to squeeze them into *one* call hempers readability, maintainability and IMHO violates Separation Of Concerns. (Just my 2 cents)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to add the entry with the total to every inner map:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, Long>> result = myProductList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Product::getDate,
        TreeMap::new, // orders entries by key, i.e. by date
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Product::getProductName,
                LinkedHashMap::new,     // LinkedHashMap is mutable and 
                Collectors.counting()), // preserves insertion order, i.e.
            map -> {                    // we can insert the total later
                map.put("Total", map.values().stream().mapToLong(c -> c).sum());
                return map;
            })));
```

The `result` map contains:

```
{2017-05-01={ABC=2, XYZ=1, Total=3}, 2017-05-02={ABC=1, Total=1}}
```

I've specified suppliers for both the outer map and the inner maps. The outer map is a `TreeMap`, which orders its entries by key (in this case by date). For the inner maps I've decided to go for `LinkedHashMap`, which is mutable and preserves insertion order, i.e. we will be able to insert the total later, once the inner maps have been filled with data.

---

So far so good. However, I think we can do it better, since, once each inner map is filled with data, we need to traverse all its values to calculate the total. (This is what `map.values().stream().mapToLong(c -> c).sum()` actually does). By doing this, we are not taking advantage of the fact that, when counting, every element of the stream adds `1` not only to the group it belongs, but also to the total. Luckily, we can solve this with a custom collector:

```
public static <T, K> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, Long>> groupsWithTotal(
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier,
    K totalKeyName) {

    class Acc {
        Map<K, Long> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        long total = 0L;

        void accumulate(T elem) {
            this.map.merge(classifier.apply(elem), 1L, Long::sum);
            this.total++;
        }

        Acc combine(Acc another) {
            another.map.forEach((k, v) -> {
                this.map.merge(k, v, Long::sum);
                this.total += v;
            });
            return this;
        }

        Map<K, Long> finish() {
            this.map.put(totalKeyName, total);
            return this.map;
        }
    }

    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::accumulate, Acc::combine, Acc::finish);
}
```

This collector not only counts elements for each group (like `Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getProductName, Collectors.counting())` does), but also adds to the total when accumulating and combining. When finishing, it also adds an entry with the total.

To use it, simply invoke the `groupsWithTotal` helper method:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, Long>> result = myProductList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Product::getDate,
        TreeMap::new,
        groupsWithTotal(Product::getProductName, "Total")));
```

The output is the same:

```
{2017-05-01={ABC=2, XYZ=1, Total=3}, 2017-05-02={ABC=1, Total=1}}
```

As a bonus, given `LinkedHashMap` supports `null` keys, this custom collector can also group by a `null` key, i.e. in the rare case that a `Product` has a `null` `productName`, it will create an entry with the `null` key instead of throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The first solution should also pass an explicit map supplier, otherwise the result is not guaranteed to be mutable.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: The second solution is more maintainable and self explaining. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is similar to others posted here, with some key differences. I've separated the inner grouping logic to its own method to keep the code more manageable. The method takes a generic Total key and throws an error in case it conflicts with a preexisting key. It also accepts a map supplier to ensure the resulting map is mutable.

```
public static <T, K, M extends Map<K, Long>> Collector<T, ?, M> countingGroups(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier, Supplier<? extends M> mapFactory, K totalKey) {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, mapFactory, Collectors.counting()),
            m -> {
                long totalValue = m.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
                if (m.put(totalKey, totalValue) != null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate mapping found for total key");
                }
                return m;
            });
}
```

We can now use this as the downstream collector for the date grouping, similar to your initial attempt:

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> counts = myProductList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getDate,
                countingGroups(Product::getProductName, HashMap::new, "Total")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a small program to get the result that you are looking for.
Also, you should see [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-).

*CollectingAndThen is a special collector that allows performing another action on a result straight after collecting ends.*

I have used `lombok` to avoid wasting time in writing constructors and `getter/setters`.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Product {
    private String name;
    private Long date;
}

public class Practice1 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Product("ABC", 1L));
        list.add(new Product("ABC", 1L));
        list.add(new Product("XYZ", 1L));
        list.add(new Product("ABC", 2L));

        Map<Long, Map<String, Long>> finalMap = list.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Product::getDate,
                                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName, Collectors.counting()),
                                        map -> {
                                            long sum = map.values().stream().reduce(0L, Long::sum);
                                            map.put("total", sum);
                                            return map;
                                        }
                                )

                        )
                );

        System.out.println(finalMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after the grouping with counting you have achieved you have something like:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> products
```

and you now want a map from the key (date) to the total of the corresponding values in the nested map. Here is a way to achieve that:

```
Map<String, Long> totals = products.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue().values().stream().mapToLong(i -> i).sum()));
```

Comment: This would partially solve my problem. Because the downstream who expects the data in the same format which I had given.